# wpf bind all sliders ‘ IsEnabledProperty in a array

Tags: arrays, wpf, binding

First I am new to wpf and a rookie programer... I have a userControl displays over 100 sliders,  I want to manage their "IsEnabledProperty" in an array, I am thinking to use binding expression, but don't know how!
Here is my code with binding expression:

I have set dataContext m_ViewModel.

```
 public bool[] ControlerEnable
        {
            set => SetProperty(ref _controlerEnable, value);
            get => _controlerEnable;
        }
```

```
             List<Slider> _sliders = GetVisualChild<Slider>(this._grid);
            for (int i = 0; i < _sliders.Count; ++i)
            {
                BindingExpression value= _sliders[i].GetBindingExpression(Slider.ValueProperty);
                string sliderValue = value.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
                int nIndex = GetIndex(sliderValue);
                Binding binding = new Binding("m_ViewModel.ControlerEnable[nIndex]");  //question here
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(_sliders[i], Slider.IsEnabledProperty, binding);
                _sliders[i].MouseDoubleClick += Slider_MouseDoubleClick;
            }
```

**Can I use index in path like that?**

Comment: Use an ItemsControl to display the Sliders. Assign a collection of data items that represent the state of a Slider to the ItemsSource property. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: For the index question, only numeric or dictionary key literals are allowed, e.g. `new Binding($"m_ViewModel.ControlerEnable[{nIndex}]")`

Comment: Yes, you can use indexers in the binding path. But there won't be any change notification as bool is a value type. So it's basically a OneTime binding in your scenario.

Comment: The solution is what Clemens suggested: use an e.g. ListBox that you populate with a data model that exposes a bool property. Then render the Slider per item using a DataTemplate.

Comment: The Binding would be pointless, you could as well directly set the IsEnabled property: `_sliders[i].IsEnabled = m_ViewModel.ControlerEnable[nIndex];`

Comment: Thank you all! I see ...seems I am thinking too simple. The limit is that those sliders are arranged in fixed position,or to say it's placed one by one... Maybe I should directly set the property.   Thanks again ! ! very helpful !